# Как создать папку на другом сервере при помощи ansible?

Tags: ansible

> Внимание! Этот вопрос является переводом вопроса: [How to create a
>   directory using
>   Ansible?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/22844905/how-to-create-a-directory-using-ansible)

Как создать папку /src/www на другом сервере при помощи ansible? Операционная система на удалённом сервере - debian или centos.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844905/how-to-create-a-directory-using-ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [модуль file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) с параметром `state=directory`.

Минимальный вариант:

```
- name: сreate directory
  file: path=/src/www state=directory
```

или:

```
- name: сreate directory
  file:
    path=/src/www
    state=directory
```

Дополнительно можно указать опциональные параметры, например, владельца папки или права на папку:

```
- name: сreate directory
  file:
    path=/src/www
    mode=0755
    owner=root
    group=root
    state=directory
```

Также обратите внимание, что создавать последовательно вложенные папки нет никакой необходимости. Вместо:

```
- name: сreate directory
  file: path=/src/www state=directory
- name: сreate subdirectory
  file: path=/src/www/logs state=directory
```

Можно сразу указывать сразу путь целиком: все необходимые папки и подпапки будут созданы автоматически.

```
- name: сreate directories
  file: path=/src/www/logs state=directory
```

Исключение -- случай, когда вам необходимо указывать различные уровни доступа, владельцев и т.п.

---

Об идемпотентности

Как и все модули ansible, file поддерживает идемпотентность выполнения. В случае, если на диске уже есть папка, которую вы пытаетесь создать, папка создаваться заново не будет.

Здесь есть один нюанс. Если вы указываете только имя папки и не удаляете каталог, а лишь меняете права доступа и/или владельца, то при повторном запуске плейбука права доступа или владельца не будут восстановлены к значениям по умолчанию, с которым была создана папка.

А вот в случае, когда вы не только указываете путь к папке, но и права доступа и владельца - то (в случае если они были изменены) ansible при повторных запусках плейбука будет не только проверять наличие папки, но и права доступа и владельца.

Например:

- папка не удалена, владелец и права доступа не изменены: задача не будет выполнена, значение changed не будет увеличено
- папка не удалена, владелец не изменился, но изменены права доступа на папку: задача будет выполнена (папка не будет пересоздаваться, лишь восстановятся права доступа), значение changes увеличится на единицу

Продемонстрирую на следующем примере. Есть скрипт создания папки:

```
- name: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609260/
  hosts: webservers
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: сreate directory
      file:
        path=/home/ansible/www
        mode=0775
        state=directory
```

Запускаем в первый раз - создаётся папка:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_development so609260.yml

PLAY [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609260/] ***************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [myserver.tld]    

TASK [сreate directory] ********************************************************
changed: [myserver.tld]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
myserver.tld : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Заходим на удалённый сервер, смотрим - всё правильно:

```
# ls -l /home/ansible
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root    root      6 дек 29 17:09 www
```

При повторном запуске скрипта - ничего не меняется:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_development so609260.yml

PLAY [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609260/] ***************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [myserver.tld]

TASK [сreate directory] ********************************************************
ok: [myserver.tld]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
myserver.tld : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Но вот если сымитировать некоторые вандальные действия (папка не удалена, но кто-то поменял права доступа):

```
# chmod 0777 /home/ansible/www
# ls -l /home/ansible
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root    root      6 дек 29 17:09 www
```

То повторный запуск восстановит права на папку:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_development so609260.yml

PLAY [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609260/] ***************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [myserver.tld]

TASK [сreate directory] ********************************************************
changed: [myserver.tld]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
myserver.tld : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Как и было:

```
# ls -l /home/ansible
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root    root      6 дек 29 17:09 www
```

Comment: Про нюанс с удалением/неудалением/правами не совсем понятно. Можно примеры конфига и результат до/после?

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил пояснение.